# Why a certain CSS effect is not working on another computer

Tags: css

I used a relatively simple hover effect to make a small text bubble popup when hovering over a table.

This is in our Zendesk HelpCenter.

On my co-worker's computer it is simply not appearing.

It can't be a version issue, because we both have access to the same published version of the article. Plus, others were able to see this.

We are both using the same browser (Chrome).

Is there any explanation for this?

```css
.tooltip {

}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
   visibility: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
  font-size:16px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
 margin-bottom:-200px;
    
 
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
 
  
}
```

```html
<table class="tooltip" style="height: 409px; border-color: black; width: 696px;" border="1px">
<thead>
<tr style="background-color: lightgrey; height: 19px;">
<td style="width: 229px; height: 19px;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-medium"><strong>1</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 222px; height: 19px;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-medium"><strong>2</strong></span></td>
<td style="width: 239px; height: 19px;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-medium"><strong>3</strong></span>
<div class="tooltiptext">popup text </div>
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 93px;">
<td style="width: 229px; height: 93px;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-large"> x</span></td>
<td style="width: 222px; height: 93px;"><span class="wysiwyg-font-size-large"> y</span></td>
<td style="width: 239px; height: 93px;">

</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a caching issue.

Check Chrome dev tools on their machine to ensure that the correct version of your CSS and HTML has been delivered to their browser. Hard refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) or reload without the cache using the dev tools.